# can I delete abstract socket path?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

I created a abstract socket.

```
#define SOCKET_PATH @/tmp/xyz /*in server code of socket_server.c*/

int sockfd = -1; 
int len; 
struct sockaddr_un address; 
int result; 
sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
if(sockfd < -1) { 
    perror("socket:"); 
} 
memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address)); 
address.sun_family = AF_UNIX; 
strcpy(address.sun_path, SOCKET_PATH); 
address.sun_path[0]='\0'; 
len = sizeof(address); 
result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, len);
```

which is successfully creating abstract socket

```
sh-3.2# netstat -a | grep xyz
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11132  @/tmp/xyz
```

now I am using the same file path to unlink the socket.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SOCKET_PATH "@/tmp/xyz"
int main()
{
        int ret;
        ret = unlink(SOCKET_PATH);
        if(ret == -1)
                perror("unlink::");
        return 0;
}
```

but when I am running the my unlinking code I am getting message as:

```
sh-3.2# ./ulink
unlink::: No such file or directory
```

Can someone tell me the reason of this "No such file or directory" and how can I delete/unlink this abstract socket from outside? Is there any method or not?

Comment: check for /tmp/xyz, withuot @, and show the code where you call socket() function

Comment: I tried /tmp/xyz and the message is same and my socket() function snippet:
int         sockfd = -1;
        int         len;
        struct sockaddr_un address;
        int         result;
        sockfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(sockfd < -1){
                perror("socket:");
        }
        memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));
        address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(address.sun_path, SOCKET_PATH);
        address.sun_path[0]='\0';
        len = sizeof(address);
        result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, len);

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Where is the server socket? Where is `listen`? Where is `bind`? What does your socket connect to?

Comment: Anyway, abstract sockets are not associated with the file system in any way (that's what makes them abstract). You cannot manipulate them with filesystem operations.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract socket has no connection with filesystem pathnames (see [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)), so that you can't use unlink().

Abstract socket should be automatically removed by kernel when no processes use it, so to "remove" it you should close all server and client descriptors referring socket or just kill all server and client processes.

Comment: What would the result be if one tried? In other words, if you took an existing server that creates a standard Unix socket file descriptor and switched it with a Linux namespace socket would you have to remove the unlink call?

Comment: @JSON unlink will return ENOENT, because the path "" does not exist.